# Use own username/password with git and bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm in a team of three; two are working locally, and I am working on the server.

My coworker set up the account, but gave me full privileges to the repository.

I set my username and email in git:

```
git config --global user.name "bozdoz"
git config --global user.email email@email.com
```

and they are identical to my username and email on bitbucket.org.

But when I pull or push to the repository it indicates their username in the prompt:

```
Password for 'https://theirusername@bitbucket.org':
```

I was able to get a prompt for my password after trying to pull by indicating the URL with my username:

```
git pull https://bozdoz@bitbucket.org/path/repo.git
```

and it said up-to-date; and then when I pushed, it said no-fast-forward.

I read that I need to specify the branch, but I don't know how to do that in a push statement while I'm also specifying the repo URL:

```
git push https://bozdoz@bitbucket.org/path/repo.git
```

I am able to pull and push if my co-worker is around and can put his password in.  But this is also listing him as the author of the push, and not me.

How can I pull and push to a repo branch as my own username?

Comment: Note: in windows, bitbucket [url/user/passwords] stored in `Credential Manager`
You can check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Run

```
git remote -v
```

and check whether your origin's URL has your co-worker's username hardcoded in there. If so, substitute it with your own:

```
git remote set-url origin <url-with-your-username>
```

Comment: That's awesome.  Thanks so much.  Worked perfectly.  New to StackOverflow? I'd like to give you some reputation if you care to have some.  I can award a bounty in 2 days.

Comment: JFYI: a) `<url-with-your-username>` doesn't exist - repo must be forked before b) push to fork doesn't change (obviously) origin

Comment: @bozdoz - must not, at least "not as expected". You have not any rights in coworker repo,

Comment: @bozdoz - BB-repo have single user, Owner. If owner isn't team

Comment: @LazyBadger Either way.  Our team has been working on the same repo for months, pushing commits every night, and it has been working fine.  So maybe there are a few circumstances where this method works.

Comment: The URL is split into your_username@bitbucket.org/owner_name/repo_name.git. It's possible that your team-member provided you with the Clone URL and you just happened to `git clone <provided_url>`, so every time you pushed/pulled you would have to authenticate against that user.

Answer (score 74):

I figured I should share my solution, since I wasn't able to find it anywhere, and only figured it out through trial and error.

I indeed was able to transfer ownership of the repository to [a team on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/account/create-team/).

***Don't*** add the remote URL that BitBuckets suggests:

```
git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/teamName/repo.git
```

***Instead***, add the remote URL without your username:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/teamName/repo.git
```

This way, when you go to pull from or push to a repo, **it prompts you for your username, then for your password**: everyone on the team has access to it under their own credentials.  This approach only works with teams on BitBucket, even though you can manage user permissions on single-owner repos.

Comment: I am trying this solution, but using `git remote set-url origin` instead of `git remote add origin`.

Instead of getting a prompt for username I am getting `The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing`

Comment: are you using https? @Anthony

Comment: Yes I am using https. `git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/XXX/YYY.git` followed by `git pull` then results in `error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing https://bitbucket.org/XXX/YYY.git/info/refs`. Putting back in the username puts everything back to normal again.

Comment: @Anthony are you trying to access a team repo, or a personal repo?

Comment: it is a team repo. It was initially a personal repo but was moved to a team after being created.

Comment: If you have already: git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/teamName/repo.git
you can change it in .git/config to

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem in order to push

Comment: To be overly clear, you can simply remove the the `@` and everything before it up until the closest `/` (exclusive of the `/`, natch) and you're golden, potentially. `https://creatorName@bitbucket.org/soCalledTeamName/project-name.git` changes to 
`https://bitbucket.org/soCalledTeamName/project-name.git` if you use `git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/soCalledTeamName/project-name.git`

Answer (score 14):

The prompt:

```
Password for 'https://theirusername@bitbucket.org':
```

suggests, that you are using https not ssh. SSH urls start with git@, for example:

```
git@bitbucket.org:beginninggit/alias.git
```

Even if you work alone, with a single repo that you own, the operation:

```
git push
```

will cause:

```
Password for 'https://theirusername@bitbucket.org':
```

if the remote origin starts with `https`.

Check your remote with:

```
git remote -v
```

The remote depends on `git clone`. If you want to use ssh clone the repo using its ssh url, for example:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git
```

I suggest you to start with `git push` and `git pull` for your private repo.

If that works, you have two joices suggested by Lazy Badger:

- Pull requests
- Team work

Comment: I guess that I am using HTTPS and not SSH, according to your answer.  Thanks for the help.  @Erik's suggestion of altering the config file ultimately solved the problem.  For future repos our team is going to do the bitbucket team method.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's part of BitBucket philosophy and workflow:

- Repository may have only one user: owner
- For ordinary accounts (end-user's) collaboration expect "fork-pull request" workflow

i.e you can't (in usual case) commit into foreign repo under own credentials.

You have two possible solutions:

1. "Classic" BB-way: fork repo (get owned by **you** repository), make changes, send pull request to origin repo
2. [Create "Team"](https://bitbucket.org/account/create-team/), add user-accounts as members of team, make Team owner of repository - it this case for this "Shared central" repository every team memeber can push under own credentials - inspect [thg](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/overview) repository and [TortoiseHg Team](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/profile/members), owner of this repository, as samples

Comment: How would we indicate which user is pushing in a team?  Do we have to set user.name each time?

Comment: @bozdoz - don't mix identity (used for local commit and transferred as is to BB) with authorization, which you must perform on push. You have to enter and store your credentials (BB-username and password, not Git's user.* parameters)

Comment: How do you enter and store credentials outside of git config? @lazybadger

Comment: @bozdoz [Permanent authentication for Git repositories over HTTP(S)] (https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=298977121) and [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github). If you use SSH things differ radically

Answer (score 3):

For myself private repo, i use

> git@bitbucket.org:username/blog.git

replace

> https://username@bitbucket.org/username/blog.git

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue where the team member left and fetch and pull commands were still referring to his account, so I need to update that URL, I followed following steps

1. run this command `git remote -v`
2. it showed the URL that is being used for fetch and pull, like this

   ```
      https://otherusername@bitbucket.org/repo.git (fetch)
      https://otherusername@bitbucket.org/repo.git (push)
   ```
3. updated this URL to inlcude my own user name

   ```
    git remote set-url origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/repo.git/
   ```
4. then I run this command to use cache as my credentials helper

   ```
    git config --global credential.helper cache
   ```
5. next when I run git fetch, it asked for password, I entered password, and it got saved, next time whenever I do fetch and pull, it reads from the saved credentials.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't pushing over SSH? Maybe check the email associated with your SSH key in bitbucket if you have one.

Comment: @LazyBadger I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I had to merge some of those good answers here! This works for me:

```
git remote set-url origin 'https://bitbucket.org/teamName/repo.git'
```

In the end, it will always prompt anyone who wants to pull from it