# Git asks for repo owner password, not for the teammate password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I came across a weird issue.
A new co-worker has joined my team. He tried to clone the repo and git has asked him for **my password**. We have verified that it doesn't accept his bitbucket password, while it accepts mine.

Some additional facts:

- He already uses git in another project, with credentials stored in netrc, and it works fine. Both repositories are on bitbucket so credentials should be the same.
- Other co-workers had no problem with cloning into this repo.
- He has a write access, just like the rest of the team.

If he had the same problem in a second repo, or another person had it, this would give me a clue. But that's not the case, and I'm confused.

Our remote repositories are hosted at bitbucket. He's using Windows.

What else could I be missing?

Comment: Is the url of the BitBucket repo (which fails to be cloned) is an ssh one, or an https one?

Comment: It's https.
I think I may have found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166722/use-own-username-password-with-git-and-bitbucket

I'll try it when that teammate is online.

Comment: Do you mean yuor login was embedded within the https url he was using?

Comment: Yes, I have send it to him via email, while I was explaning him the tasks. Up to today I haven't known it's relevant.

Comment: Ok. I have added an answer which illustrates what could have happened here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is asking for your password, it means it tries to authenticate with your login.

That means, if the repo was cloned (using your password), a `git remote -v` must show an url like:

```
https://YourLogin@server/path/to/repo
```

You can instruct the user to change the remote url named '`origin`' with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://HisLogin@server/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I thought that MyUsername part is there simply because it's my repo. That was silly of me. And thus I have sent my clone URL to a co-worker.