# SourceTree - remote: Unauthorized

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

After updating my SourceTree application I got this error when I try to push:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin artem_XXX:artem_XXX
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://XXX@bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX-android.git/'


Pushing to https://XXX@bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX.git
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to what may have caused this?

Comment: could be possible your password saved with the app is lost..just check once

Comment: @nullpointer - I check my password in Settings

Comment: @nullpointer but this doesn't help me(

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15167400/1746118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. Have tried inputting/resetting my GitHub password multiple times. I also disabled 2FA. Can pull data, but not push. Recently updated to SourceTree 1.6.24.

Update:
Seems like others are having problems as well:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3944

Comment: yes, I downgraded but now I get new error - http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0004/0191/303295/151201/c905f8014c.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Wikzo is right. The error is already reported to be fixed and marked as major bug. Anyway, Atlassian published a proper workaround (and not downgrading) as described in their bug tracking page https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3944.
You just copy and paste a file within SourceTree directory (you can find it following the link) and the problem is solved!