# Gitkraken bitbucket token invalid

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket, gitkraken

I am using gitkraken on linux and it is excellent application. When I authenticate with bibucket, app will connect.

But when I try to make push, app will display error in top panel:

```
Your oAuth token for 'Bitbucket' is invalid. Would you like to refresh 
your oAuth credentials or try again without oAuth?
```

When I will select "Refresh Token" option I have to reconnect to bitbucket with the same result

"Retry without oAuth" option not connect (without error message), althought on bitbucket.org same login/pass work.

Originly I used another bitbucket account and that works, but with new one I cannot manage it.

Do someone has similar experience? Did you solve it?

Comment: You have to change repo owner. This helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166722/use-own-username-password-with-git-and-bitbucket

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve it by deleting the remote and adding it again.

Comment: Worked for me somehow, thanks !

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Spent a lot of time trying different things and then a basic deletion and re-cloning worked.

Answer (score 4):

I tried a couple of things and it worked for me:

- close git graken
- opened powershell / cmd and navigate to the repo
- `git pull`
- open git kraken
- go into the preferences (the little burger on the top right)
- integrations, re-enter the token from gitlab or whichever tool you might be using

Alternately, I also tried closing the repo in git kraken and opening it from the main page also. it works for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I deleted and recloned my repo and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used "GitHub Desktop". It showed the conflicts and once i fix them, i run GitKraken and the top panel asking for "oauth" disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check also if organisation allows commits with email you have saved in Git credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the invalid token easily:

1. Click on "go to GitHub" when you have the red error box in the bottom left of the GitKraken screen
2. Once GitHub is open in the browser, REVOKE the access (don't worry you are going to add it in the next step)
3. Re-try to pull or push in GitKraken
4. It will ask you if you want to refresh the Oauth token or continue without
5. Select refresh
6. Follow the instructions on the browser
7. Done